# How to get a flash message to show with passport-local logout method?

Tags: express, ejs, passport-local, flash-message

I am unable to show a flash message of 'You have successfully logged out' when trying to use the req.logout() method using passport-local.

Here is what I currently have, which will redirect to the login page but not display the message.

```
logout: (req, res, next) => {
      req.logout((err) => {
         if (err) {
            return next(err)
         }
      })
      req.flash('success_msg', 'You have successfully logged out')
      res.redirect('/login')
   }
```

If I comment out the req.logout code, the flash message will show up as well as redirect to the login page.

```
logout: (req, res, next) => {
      // req.logout((err) => {
      //    if (err) {
      //       return next(err)
      //    }
      // })
      req.flash('success_msg', 'You have successfully logged out')
      res.redirect('/login')
   }
```

I am wondering how to use req.logout() and also get the flash message to show to the user.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the `req.flash()` and `res.redirect()` needed to be inside of the `req.logout()` callback and in my code above it was outside of it.

```
logout: (req, res, next) => {
  req.logout((err) => {
    if (err) {
      return next(err)
    }
    req.flash('success_msg', 'You have successfully logged out')
    res.redirect('/login')
  })
}
```